# Sending parameters to every method call in a block

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

Instead of doing:

```
calc(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
calc(a: 1, b: 2, c: 10)
calc(a: 1, b: 2, c: 2)
calc(a: 1, b: 2, c: 103)
calc(a: 1, b: 2, c: 98)
```

I would do:

```
with_parameters(a: 1, b: 2) do
  calc(c: 3)
  calc(c: 10)
  calc(c: 2)
  calc(c: 103)
  calc(c: 98)
end
```

Context is I'm trying to do this for FactoryGirl, e.g. create lots of similar factories

**Edit**: Actually I'm pretty sure some `method_missing` + `send` could do that

Answer (score 1):

For factory girl, there's no need for any fancy tricks

```
let(:base_params) { { a: 1, b: 2} }

let(:things) { 
  [3, 10, 2].map do |c|
    create(:whatever, base_params.merge(c: c))   
  end
}
```